# How do forests grow in Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri

How many adjacent squares of forest do I have to plant before they will begin to expand?

And is there a formula, such that the more adjacent forest squares, the greater chance of auto expansion?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an authoritative answer, but I believe that each turn, each forest square has a very small chance of expanding to a random adjacent square. So the more forest squares already on the map, the more random forest square expansions will occur per turn. I believe this expansion mechanic also applies to fungus, but is less noticeable to the player since the game doesn't notify you of fungus expansions like it does for forest expansions.

Comment: Note that this means that for the *best* effect, you should plant in a checkerboard pattern so that every tile of forest has the maximum possible free adjacent squares to expand into.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks! I have been planting in contiguous blocks.

Comment: @Mark "the game doesn't notify you of fungus expansions" - I have seen it do so